# Define new argument for an extended class's method

Tags: magento2

in Magento 2.1.11 with PHP 7.0, I need to extend `formatDate($date, $includeTime = true)` method in [`Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Stdlib/DateTime.php#L47-L62) and **add third argument to it**.

I created a new module and override this method by preference its class in **di.xml**:

```
<preference for="Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime" type="MyVendor\MyModule\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime"/>
```

and **MyVendor\MyModule\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime.php** is:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Framework\Stdlib;

class DateTime extends \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime{

    public function formatDate($date, $includeTime = true, $myArg = false){

    ...}

}
```

But after use this method in my template file (order/recent.phtml) like this:

```
echo $block->formatDate(time(),true,true);
```

The third argument **$myArg** *always is false!*

What can I do for adding this third argument to this method!?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If following Magento best practices, you cannot do this. Magento 2 prefers composition over inheritance. Best practice states that you should not extend and modify.

Additionally, the method's arguments are likely restricted by the rules set forth in an interface.

It sounds like the right solution for you would be a before, around, or after plugin, depending on what you would like to accomplish.

Comment: So, Magento is not that so flexible with it's core changing! :(

Comment: @MehranZarei It's actually extremely flexible. Interfaces are used to set specific rules to ensure that your customizations ALWAYS work. You should really become familiar with Magento 2's "plugin" system, it is super helpful. Alan Storm has written some very good tutorials on how to use them.